# Can I setup a "View only mode" for Awesome-WM?

Tags: xorg, awesome, rdesktop

I'm using [Awesome-WM](http://awesome.naquadah.org/) and would like to setup a keyboard-toggle and/or window match rule that changes the way inputs are processed for that window. Basically I would like the option to mark a Window as "view only" so that no keyboard or mouse input is passed through to the program.

My primary use case involves `rdesktop` which sadly doesn't have a way to connect to a remove machine in view-only mode and also is somewhat too greedy about detecting keyboard input, but I've also run into wanting this for other programs that I would like to monitor without accidentally passing them mouse activity.

I've tried setting up a rule to disable the *focusable* property, but this doesn't seem to have any effect:

```
{ rule_any = {
        class = { "rdesktop" }
    },
    properties = {
        focus = false,
        focusable = false,
        floating = true,
        sticky = true,
        ontop = true,
        opacity = 0.5
    }
}
```

All the other properties set here behave as expected, but the focus options do not disable the window from receiving focus and subsequent input events.

Is there a way to configure this? As a bonus it would be nice to be able to setup a floating window as on-top but  pass all input through to the window behind it. Is that a possibility?

Comment: Just guessing: arrange for the window to have a [rule](http://awesome.naquadah.org/wiki/Understanding_Rules) with `focus=false`?

Comment: @Gilles  Sadly it's not quite that easy. I'm not sure exactly what if anything that does because even with such a rule applied the window still receives input events of all sorts. I have a rule already that positions the window, marks it as on top, adds transparency, etc. Adding `properties =  { focus = false } ` to that rule has no apparent effect.

Comment: @Gilles Likewise for the `focusable` property which sounded really promising when I found it in the API docs but did nothing useful when I applied it.